# Complex integral by residues

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Let $R=\{z\in\mathbb{C}: -1/2<\Re(z)<3/2, -1<\Im(z)< 1\}.$ We wish to evaluate
$$\int_C \frac{\cos(3z)}{\sin(4z)}dz, $$
where $C$ is the boundary of $R$ oriented clockwise. For simplicity, denote the integrand by $f(x)$.

We note that $\sin(4z)=0 \iff z=k\pi/4$, for any $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. However, $k\pi/4\in R \iff k=0\mbox{ or }1$.

The zeros of $\sin(4z)$ at $0\mbox{ and }\pi/4$ are simple, and $\cos(0),\cos(3\pi/4)\ne 0$. Therefore, we use "The $p/q'$ formula" to get
$$Res(f,0) = \frac{\cos(0)}{4\cos(0)}=\frac{1}{4},$$
$$Res(f,\pi/4) = \frac{\cos(3\pi/4)}{4\cos(\pi)}=\frac{1}{4\sqrt{2}}.$$
So, Cauchy's Residue Theorem tells us
$$\int_C \frac{\cos(3z)}{\sin(4z)}dz = 2\pi i\left(\frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{4\sqrt{2}}\right)=\frac{\pi i}{2}\left(1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right).$$

> Is this correct? I am rather new to complex integrals in general, and especially by residues.

Comment: The residue at $\pi/4$ looks strange. You seem to forget the $3$ and $4$ in $\cos(3z)/\cos(4z)$.

Comment: @mickep I revised my working. Would you be able to check once more, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it looks correct. Good luck with your residues.